# Tkinter canvas not updating photo

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-button

I am trying to make a photo editing app with tkinter that preforms an action to the uploaded picture on a button press(eg. flips the picture), but when the button is pressed nothing happens. The code that manipulates the picture works, I just can't get the change to show on screen.
Full code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import PIL
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

image = PIL.Image.open('images.jpg')

img_data = np.array(image)


def button_flip_onClick():
    global canvas
    global image_container
    global img
    image_flipped_data = np.flip(img_data, axis=1)
    image_flipped = Image.fromarray(image_flipped_data)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_flipped)
    image_container.config(canvas.create_image(10,10,anchor='nw',image=img))


SCREEN_WIDTH = 300
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 300

root = tk.Tk()


canvas = tk.Canvas(width=SCREEN_WIDTH, height=SCREEN_HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()
#Load an image in the script
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)



image_container = canvas.create_image(10,10,anchor='nw',image=img)


button2 = tk.Button(root, text='flip', command= lambda:button_flip_onClick)
button2.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.7, relheight=0.15, relwidth=0.2)



root.mainloop()
```

I've tried configuring img in the function, putting image_container after button2, configuring the canvas in the function. All resulted in the picture staying the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the import part first.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
```

and,
In button_flip_onClick function

```
image_container.config(canvas.create_image(10,10,anchor='nw',image=img))
```

Replace this part with:

```
canvas.itemconfig(image_container, image=img)
```

And when your button calls a function, you don't need a lambda. It works even if you do this.

```
button2 = tk.Button(root, text='flip', command= button_flip_onClick)
```

and full code...

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk

image = Image.open('images.jpg')

img_data = np.array(image)

def button_flip_onClick():
    global canvas
    global image_container
    global img
    image_flipped_data = np.flip(img_data, axis=1)
    image_flipped = Image.fromarray(image_flipped_data)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_flipped)
    canvas.itemconfig(image_container, image=img)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 300
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 300

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(width=SCREEN_WIDTH, height=SCREEN_HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()
#Load an image in the script
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

image_container = canvas.create_image(10,10,anchor='nw',image=img)

button2 = tk.Button(root, text='flip', command= button_flip_onClick)
button2.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.7, relheight=0.15, relwidth=0.2)

root.mainloop()
```

I hope it will be of help.